# PHP array undefined offset 0 after value insert

Tags: php, arrays

I have problem accessing the array value after I insert it to array.

This code

```
$array = array();
$array[] = "item";
var_dump($array);
```

displays this output

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "item"
}
```

So far it's ok. When I add this two lines

```
$item = $array[0];
var_dump($item);
```

I get this output

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in script.php on line 4
NULL
```

When I try to search the item with array_search

```
$offset = array_search("item", $array);
var_dump($offset);
```

output

```
int(0);
```

Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: you must put the whole context.. maybe you are using some references..

Comment: That code works fine and without any warnings.

Comment: We assume this is all happening in the same piece of code and not seperate scripts? **Right?**

Comment: maybe there is u used an array_shift, or unset before printing the `$item`.

Comment: can you include what PHP version you are using and are they in the same file?

Comment: its work fine return these .... array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "item" }  and string(4) "item"

Comment: Yes it is a part of code. I already found my mistake. I didn't realize that I am inserting $array["something"][] and then accessing $array[0]. Sorry for my stupid question :) Thx for an effort guys.